# Unable to implement authorization with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp-net-mvc-1

I am using asp.net core 2.2. I created an empty web application using Visual Studio 2019. I added this code in Startup.cs, in the configure services method:

```
    services.AddMvc(config =>
{
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
.Build();
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

So my method looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>();



        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();

            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        //services.AddMvc();
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SQLEmployeeRepository>();
    }
```

I expected this to make the whole application require authorization, however if I go to any controller and action, I can just view that without signing in. Do I need to do anything extra to configure this or force it?

I tried to add the [Authorize] attribute on the class itself. Here's how the beginning of my controller looks like:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EmployeeManagement.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; 
namespace EmployeeManagement.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

.
.
.
```

What else do I need to do to force pages to require login/authorization?

Comment: How are you authenticating your user?

Comment: I am using asp.net core identity. I am following these tutorials: https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/06/aspnet-core-identity-tutorial-from.html

Comment: Plesae see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59476691/5576498

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need to update the Configure method in the Startup as well to enable authorization. Try adding this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

[image: NuGet package required]

Comment: it doesn't work if I do so as I get a message: IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseAuthorization. I guess it was introduced with asp.net 3 while am using asp.net 2.2?

Comment: Add the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App. I believe that has the authentication functionality you need.

Comment: Hi Chad, I already have Microsoft.AspNetCore.App metapackage installed. with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization installed as well.

Comment: I am able to get it to work with .NET Core 2.2 with the NuGet package I mentioned. I updated my answer with a screenshot of the NuGet package as it appears in the Visual Studio Package Manager screen. I hope that helps :)

Comment: hi Chad, I have the same package installed. However when I try to use app.UseAuthorization, I have red squiggly line under the method name and it tells me it's not available.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[Authorize]`, use the following Attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```